# SELECT Permutation of Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 7 columns containing items (and other columns with data). When i store the (game)Data the order of the items is important. But now i want to do a query where the order is not relevant, just that the user has used the specific combination of items.

Edit: I want all results where a specific Character (cID) has used item 1,2,3,... in a game. It's not important if the player used an item as the first item (item1) or last.

```
id  |cID  |item1   |item2   |item3   
 1  | 5   | 3      | 1      | 0      
 2  | 1   | 4      | 2      | 1      
 3  | 2   | 1      | 3      | 2
 4  | 2   | 2      | 2      | 2
```

Currently the query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   userdata 
WHERE  item1 IN (1,2,3) 
AND    item2 IN (1,2,3) 
AND    item3 IN (1,2,3) 
AND    cID = 2
```

But then i have to filter the results. In this example I only want id 3 but get id 3 and id 4.

Is there a way to do this direct with the query?

EDIT2:
The plain text query would be like this:

Give me all rows where a user played x character and used these 7 items.

The user can use the items in any order. The data I get contains the order in which the user used the items. But for this query this order is not relevant, its only relevant if the user used the specific item set at all in one game. (1,2,3) and (2,3,1) is equivalent. The user can have also the same item multiple times, meaning (1,1,1) is a valid entry for a user having the item '1' three times.

Having all permutations in the query would mean over 5k 'OR' statements when the searched item set contains 7 different items. This would work but seems not right.

Like for the example, a query for the item set (1,2,3) would look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   userdata 
WHERE  
     (item1 = 1 AND item2 = 2 AND item3 = 3 AND cID = 2) 
OR 
     (item1 = 1 AND item2 = 3 AND item3 = 2 AND cID = 2) 
OR 
     (...)
```

Comment: "When i store the Data the order is important" -> If this is true than you should not use a SQL database, because the results of an SQL statement are un-orderded by default (unless you specify an `ORDER BY`(

Comment: If you just want 1 result row, you can add a `LIMIT 1` to your query, but you need to add `ORDER BY id` to make sure `3` is selected and not `4`.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks, maybe I wrote it stupid. I need to know that the order of item1/item2/.... for other querys. Here I want all cases where a user has a special set of items. But the order is for this case not relevant. aka its not important if the user used the item as item1 or item2 ...

Comment: If the order is not important, you could use BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to ensure that items are sorted in the same way: lowest value - first, highest value - third. Then you would have to sort search parameters too and get an efficient query WHERE item1=1 and item2=2 and item3=3.

Comment: @Naktibalda the order is important. This is the only query where the order is not important.

Comment: *In this example I only want id 3* why?

Comment: @C14L you started your comment with *my guess is ...*. For me, this is enough not only to downvote but also to close a question as unclear.

Comment: @forpas exactly like C14L said. I want all rows wich have a specific item combination. The user can use the items in any order. So for this query (1,2,3) and (2,3,1) are equivalent.  the Set of items is important not the order aka. in which column the item appears. For all other queries on the dataset the order aka. item1 item2 etc. IS important, so inserting the items in different order is not possible

Comment: *exactly like C14L said* this what **you** should say in your question.

Comment: @C14L My comments where justified and clear. You should direct your advice to the OP with the link How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   userdata 
WHERE  item1 IN (1,2,3) 
AND    item2 IN (1,2,3) AND item2 NOT IN (item1)
AND    item3 IN (1,2,3) AND item3 NOT IN (item1, item2)
AND    cID = 2
```

But there is probably a more elegant way.

Comment: Tanks that works for most of the cases! Just the edge case when a user has the same item multiple times will not work.

Comment: Please clarify: The same item value multiple times in the same row? Or multiple rows with the same combination of item values? In the later case, you could just add 'LIMIT 1` so that you get only one of the repeated rows.

Comment: One item in the same row in different columns. When a user buys 6 times the same item in one match, all item[1-6] Columns would be the same value in that row.

Comment: Do you mean that your query may contain the same number multiple times? Like `... WHERE  item1 IN (3,3,3) ...` for example?

Comment: Exactly! I have edited the question to clarify this

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the items is unclear, and you want to select there different items, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   userdata 
WHERE  item1 IN (1,2,3) 
AND    item2 IN (1,2,3) and item2<>item1
AND    item3 IN (1,2,3) and item3<>item1 and item3<>item2
AND    cID = 2;
```

This will select a row where items `1`,`2` and `3` exist, and no longer select the row where you just have items with the value `2`.

Note: this will not be a performant solution. Only if you use ordered items (as was suggested by @Naktibalda in the comments) you might find a more performant solution.

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff8c5a385f9421c216c7bc8731a35100)